# MySQL round() not working as expected with sum()

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query;

```
select round(sum(quantity * calories)) as calories
from tableName;
```

where quantity and calories are of type double and having the values 1.00 & 110.50 respectively. I'm expecting an output of 111, but the above query is instead giving me 110. But if I execute a simple query like the below,

```
select round (110.50);
```

It's giving me 111 as the output. I went through this [Link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61867), and used a query like the following;

```
select round(sum(cast(quantity * calories as char))) as calories
from tableName;
```

but this one also not working for me and giving 110 as output. Can someone tell how to arrive at the desired output of 111?

Comment: Is this query being applied over a single record, or an entire table?  Can you give us sample data to show some context here?

Comment: Yeah, I'm applying it to a single record.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is known to not be exact in programming languages (including MySQL).  My guess is that there is slight variation which is resulting in the round going down instead of up.  I wouldn't lose sleep over this; if you have a real table and you are experiencing serious rounding problems, then update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do calculations with floating point numbers, it is better to use decimal(m,d) datatype rather than float / double as both float and double represent approximate numeric data values and are prone to rounding errors when used with calculations.

For your query you can use:

```
select round(cast(sum(quantity * calories) as decimal(8,1))) as calories
from tableName;
```

Comment: It's giving me the correct output, but can you explain what that decimal(8, 1) doing exactly.

Comment: Came to know about decimal(M, D) from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818046/what-does-m-d-mean-in-decimalm-d-exactly/1818057). I think this solution is fine.

Answer (score 2):

TRY:::

```
SELECT ROUND ( CAST ( SUM (quantity * calories) AS DECIMAL(10,4))) AS calories
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: @karthi, please refer to the edited answer. that should do it. (y)

Comment: It's similar to @slaakso's solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by casting the arguments first to DECIMAL. Then we performed the SUM / ROUND operation as DECIMAL.

```
SELECT round( sum( 
    CAST(quantity AS DECIMAL(10,4)) * 
    CAST(calories AS DECIMAL(10,4)) ) ) AS calories
FROM tableName;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tableName;

+----+----------+----------+
| id | quantity | calories |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |    110.5 |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0,02 sec)

mysql> SELECT round( sum(
    ->     CAST(quantity AS DECIMAL(10,4)) *
    ->     CAST(calories AS DECIMAL(10,4)) ) ) AS calories
    -> FROM tableName;
+----------+
| calories |
+----------+
|      111 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**sample 2 with DECIMAL(10,2)**

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tableName
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quantity` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calories` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * from tableName;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | quantity | calories |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |      1.0 |   110.50 |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select round(sum(quantity * calories)) as calories
    -> from tableName;
+----------+
| calories |
+----------+
|      111 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: It's giving me the desired output but I have a doubt. The datatype of quantity & calories is already decimal(10,2), why we need to cast it again to decimal. Please explain

Comment: You wrote: "where quantity and calories are of type **double**". Now you write its decimal(2,2). **decimal(2,2)** cant store your values. A packed "exact" fixed-point number. M is the total number of digits (the precision) and D is the number of digits after the decimal point (the scale). see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/decimal/ . i downvote

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake from my side. quantity and calories are of type double(10, 2) only. Your answer is somewhat similar to what @slaakso has provided, only the number of the cast is different  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have add a sample in my answer